# Página redireciona e o formulário de contato não é enviado via email

Tags: php, javascript, html5, formulário

A página é redirecionada, mas o formulário não é enviado. Acredito que o "email.php" não está sendo executado.

Já tentei diversos recursos diferentes, o problema que esse framework de estilos e javascripts utilizados no projeto é uma mistura de bootstrap modificado com outros recursos. Quem puder ajudar a resolver esse problema eu agradeço <3

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="contato1" id="contato1" src="./php/email.php"></iframe>

    <form class="form-input-classic" action="./php/email.php" name="contato_form" id="contato_form" method="post"
 target="contato1" 

    onsubmit="alert('Olá, ' + nome.value +' sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');

    window.location.href = 'https://Página que eu quero e está sendo redirecionada :)';

    return true;">
 


    <!--<div class="lp-section-video">
    <div class="lp-section-video-mockup" style="background-image: url(./img/secao/iphone3.png);">
    -->
        <fieldset style="background-color:#f7fbff;border-radius:30px;">
        
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Contato</h2>

        <label for="nome">Nome</label>

        <input type="text" id="nomeid" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required="required" name="nome" />
        <br>

        <label for="fone">Telefone</label>

        <input type="tel" id="foneid" placeholder="(xx)x-xxxx-xxxx" name="telefone" required="required" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>

        <input type="email" id="emailid" placeholder="exemplo@email.com" name="email" required="" />

        <br><br>

        <textarea  minlength="30" id="textareaid" name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem aqui."
 cols="90" rows="8" style="resize:none";></textarea>
        <br><br>

        <div class="form-submit-classic">

        <input type="submit" class="form-submit-classic" id="enviar" value="Enviar" data-ref="button-sib">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

O Código em php é este:
Obs: Eu alterei os endereços de email e nome do site para ter privacidade.

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $nome= addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $telefone = addslashes($_POST['telefone']);
    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $mensagem = addslashes($_POST['mensagem']);

    $to = "meuemaildecontato";
    $subject = "Contato - NomedoMeuSite";

    $body = "Nome: ".$nome. "\r\n".
            "Telefone: ".$telefone. "\r\n".
            "Email: ".$email. "\r\n".
            "Mensagem: ".$mensagem;

    $header = "From: emaildeenvio"."\r\n".
                "Reply-To:".$email."\r\n".
                "X=Mailer:PHP/" .phpversion();

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);


/*if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header)){

        echo(
            'Sua Mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!'
        #<script> 
            #alert('Olá, ' + nome.value +' sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
window.location.href = 'https://Sitequeeugostariade redirecionar';
        #   </script>

        );


    }else{

        echo(
            'Sua mensagem não foi enviada, tente novamente mais tarde.'
            #<script> 
            #alert('Olá, ' + nome.value +' sua mensagem não foi enviada, tente novamente mais tarde.');
            #</script>
        );
    }
*/

}


?>
```

Comment: Muito provavelmente o seu arquivo email.php não está sendo executado pois não existe um campo com o name "submit" sendo enviado do formulário para ele. teste colocar antes do if um var_dump($_POST);die; para ver se existe

Comment: Julyano deus te abençoe imensamente, eu te amo cara ! KKKKKKKKKKKK QUEBREI A CABEÇA HÁ 2 DIAS

Answer (score 0):

Os event listeners são executados antes do action. A lógica disso é que o action já é executado fora da página e ao executar os event listeners antes permite-se que o javascript decida se deverá ou não executar o action (com o return `true` ou `false`).

Assim sendo, a razão para o email nunca ser enviado é que o próprio javascript faz o redirecionamento para outra página antes de executar o action.

Para resolver o problema, remova o seu `onsubmit` e coloque a lógica de redirecionamento no php.